# Mysql - detectar creación nueva tabla

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estoy trabajando con una BBDD MySQL en la que necesito detectar la creación de tablas, y ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado tras cada creación de una nueva tabla. ¿Alguien sabe si hay forma de hacerlo? Sé que los triggers sólo pueden definirse tras update delete o insert, por lo que lo único que se me ha ocurrido es buscar dónde se almacenan los metadatos relativos a las tablas , y crear un trigger sobre la tabla en cuestión de los metadatos del SGBD, pero no encuentro información al respecto, ni creo que mi usuario del SGBD tenga permiso para acceder a dichas tablas, en caso de que mysql las contemple.
  ¿Alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: Sé que puedo ejecutar "select full tables from 'squema'", pero de esta forma no sé cuál es la tabla nueva que se ha creado ..

Comment: ¿Necesitas ejecutar el procedimiento inmediatamente después de la creación de la tabla? ¿o no importa si se ejecuta un poquito después de la creación?.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre implementar una tabla auxiliar que almacene el listado de tablas del esquema en el cual estas trabajando, para ello almacenaremos solamente el nombre de las tablas.

```
CREATE TABLE tables_aux(
    table_name VARCHAR(240) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(table_name)
);
```

Después crear un procedimiento que actualice dicha tabla auxiliar según la información de tablas que posea el esquema.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE update_tables_aux()
BEGIN   
    DECLARE taux, tschema VARCHAR(240);

    -- cursor que recupera las tablas del esquema y los compara con la tabla auxiliar
    DECLARE cur_tables CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT information_schema.tables.table_name tschema, tables_aux.table_name taux
        FROM information_schema.tables
        LEFT JOIN tables_aux ON tables_aux.table_name = information_schema.tables.table_name
        WHERE table_schema = 'esquema_nombre';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur_tables;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur_tables  INTO tschema, taux;

        IF @done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        IF taux IS NULL THEN
            -- es insertado el nombre de la tabla ya que si se cumple ésta condición
            -- la tabla es nueva.
            INSERT INTO tables_aux(table_name) VALUES (tschema);
        END IF;

        IF tschema IS NULL THEN
           -- es borrado de  la tabla auxiliar ya que si se cumple ésta condición
           -- la tabla fue borrada.
           DELETE FROM tables_aux WHERE table_name = taux;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END; //
```

Después de ejecutar la creación del procedimiento, llamamos al procedure para que cargue la lista de tablas existentes.

```
call update_tables_aux();
```

Creamos un evento que sea ejecutado cada minuto y que en cada ejecución llame al procedimiento de actualización `update_tables_aux` para que así se actualicé la información de tablas auxiliar.

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS run_update_tables_aux;

DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` EVENT `run_update_tables_aux`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2018-05-29 00:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
DO 
BEGIN
  CALL update_tables_aux;
END //
```

Por último implementamos un trigger a la tabla `tables_aux` entonces dicho trigger se estaría ejecutando cada vez que el procedimiento de `update_tables_aux` encuentre nuevas tablas.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER check_new_tables AFTER INSERT ON tables_aux
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
            -- código.
       END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, "Blasito" !!! Ayer estuve mirando cosillas, y avancé un poquito más en la solución, pero me has dado buenas ideas. En principio no es crítico que se cree un poquito después de la creación..

Comment: Blasito, aunque tu idea me ha parecido fantástica, creo que al final lo que voy a hacer es crear un procedimiento que compruebe si se ha creado una tabla posterior a la fecha en que se realizó dicha consulta por última vez, y así, sin utilizar tabla intermedia ni nada, logra "enterarse" de la creación de las tablas. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.